# Append dynamic data into table body using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append dynamic data into the table body using jquery with the following code. don't know where I am wrong.

```
var tr = '<tr class="v-middle">';
      tr += '<td><span><i class="'.icon_code.' _icons"></i></span></td>';
      tr += '<td class="flex text-color">'+icon_name+'</td>';
      tr += '<td class="text-color">'+icon_code+'</td>';
      tr += '<td class="text-color">'+icon_code_css+'</td>';
      tr += '<td><span class="text-color">Material Design</span></td>';
      tr += '<td><span class="badge bg-primary-lt">Copy</span> <span class="badge bg-primary-lt">Copy script</span></td>';
      tr += "</tr>";
     $('#icontable tbody').append(tr);
```

Getting the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Comment: Use `+` instead of `.` in second line

Comment: `"'.icon_code.' `this is not properly escaped

Comment: MaheeAli and Kunal say right you nedd to replace . to +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol 'is considered controlling, so it must be escaped (\'). and because of this, you get an invalid value instead of a string.

It will be correct like this:

```
var tr = '<tr class="v-middle">';
      tr += '<td><span><i class=\'.icon_code.\'_icons></i></span></td>';
      tr += '<td class="flex text-color">'+icon_name+'</td>';
      tr += '<td class="text-color">'+icon_code+'</td>';
      tr += '<td class="text-color">'+icon_code_css+'</td>';
      tr += '<td><span class="text-color">Material Design</span></td>';
      tr += '<td><span class="badge bg-primary-lt">Copy</span> <span class="badge bg-primary-lt">Copy script</span></td>';
      tr += "</tr>";
```

And if you wanted your class to be called the contents of the icon_code variable, you need to do this:

```
var tr = '<tr class="v-middle">';
      tr += '<td><span><i class=.' + icon_code + '. _icons></i></span></td>';
      tr += '<td class="flex text-color">'+ icon_name+'</td>';
      tr += '<td class="text-color">'+icon_code+'</td>';
      tr += '<td class="text-color">'+icon_code_css+'</td>';
      tr += '<td><span class="text-color">Material Design</span></td>';
      tr += '<td><span class="badge bg-primary-lt">Copy</span> <span class="badge bg-primary-lt">Copy script</span></td>';
      tr += "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong concatenation operator in your second line of code:

`tr += '<td><span><i class="'.icon_code.' _icons"></i></span></td>';`

should be

`tr += '<td><span><i class="' + icon_code + ' _icons"></i></span></td>';`